# AstroJs pass data into getStaticPaths()

Tags: javascript, astrojs

I am building a blog index page with url:mysite/blog/[year]/[month]/[date]/[slug]
and tried to put a index.astro in blog, [year] and [month] directories,
so I can show different blog index with /blog , blog/[year] and blog/[year]/[month]
according to all time , "the year" or "the year and month".

I managed to sort the dynamic route for the year because it is not so difficult to reduce my blog posts content to be arranged by the year.

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const posts = await getCollection('blogMD')
  let postsByYear = posts
    .map((post) => post.data)
    .sort(
      (a, b) =>
        -new Date(a.publishedAt).getTime() + new Date(b.publishedAt).getTime()
    )
    .reduce((newData, post) => {
      if (!newData[post.year]) newData[post.year] = []
      newData[post.year].push(post)
      return newData
    }, {})
  postsByYear = Object.entries(postsByYear)
  return postsByYear.map((year: any[]) => ({
    params: {
      year: year[0]
    },
    props: year[1]
  }))
}
```

However when I tried the month index I kind got stuck because I would like to pass the year into getStaticPaths() to filted out the posts first then reduce them to be arranged by the month, so I wouldn't have to create much bigger route table which includes both year and month.

Is there anyway to pass data into getStaticPaths()?

I tried to use
`const {year} = Asrto.params`
within and out getStaticPaths() but niether of them worked.